# Efficient looping through dictionary with keys as tuple

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a very large dictionary with 200 million keys. The keys are tuple with integer as individual elements of the tuple. I want to search for the key where the "query integer" lies within the two integers of the tuple in dictionary keys.

Currently, I am looping through all dictionary keys and comparing the integer with each element of tuple if it lies within that range. It works but the time to look up each query is around 1-2 minutes and I need to perform around 1 Million such queries. The example of the dictionary and the code which I have written are following:

Sample dictionary:

```
[{ (3547237440, 3547237503) : {'state': 'seoul teukbyeolsi', 'country': 'korea (south)', 'country_code': 'kr', 'city': 'seoul'} },
{ (403044176, 403044235) : {'state': 'california', 'country': 'united states', 'country_code': 'us', 'city': 'pleasanton'} },
{ (3423161600, 3423161615) : {'state': 'kansas', 'country': 'united states', 'country_code': 'us', 'city': 'lenexa'} },
{ (3640467200, 3640467455) : {'state': 'california', 'country': 'united states', 'country_code': 'us', 'city': 'san jose'} },
{ (853650485, 853650485) : {'state': 'colorado', 'country': 'united states', 'country_code': 'us', 'city': 'arvada'} },
{ (2054872064, 2054872319) : {'state': 'tainan', 'country': 'taiwan', 'country_code': 'tw', 'city': 'tainan'} },
{ (1760399104, 1760399193) : {'state': 'texas', 'country': 'united states', 'country_code': 'us', 'city': 'dallas'} },
{ (2904302140, 2904302143) : {'state': 'iowa', 'country': 'united states', 'country_code': 'us', 'city': 'hampton'} },
{ (816078080, 816078335) : {'state': 'district of columbia', 'country': 'united states', 'country_code': 'us', 'city': 'washington'} },
{ (2061589204, 2061589207) : {'state': 'zhejiang', 'country': 'china', 'country_code': 'cn', 'city': 'hangzhou'} }]
```

The code I have written:

```
ipint=int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip))
for k in ip_dict.keys():
    if ipint >= k[0] and ipint <= k[1]:
       print(ip_dict[k]['country'], ip_dict[k]['country_code'], ip_dict[k]['state'])
```

where ip is just ipaddress like '192.168.0.1'.

If anyone could provide a hint regarding more efficient way to perform this task, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried distributing your work using multi-threading

Comment: No, do you mean running different queries in parallel?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use another structure with a good query complexity like a tree.

Maybe you can try this library I just found https://pypi.org/project/rangetree/

As they say, it is optimized for lookups but not for insertions so if you need to insert once and lopk many it should be OK.

Another solution is to not used a dict but a list, to order it and to build an index over it. Do a dichotomy on this index when there is a query (can be less optimal if ranges are not regular so I prefer the first solution)

Answer (score 2):

Create a index for each of the 2 integers: a sorted list like this:

```
[(left_int, [list_of_row_ids_that have_this_left_int]),
 (another_greater_left_int, [...])]
```

You can then search for all rows that have a left int greater than the searched one in log(n). 
A binary search will do here.

Do the same for the right int.

Keep the rest of the data in a list of tuples.

More in detail:

```
data = [( (3547237440, 3547237503), {'state': 'seoul'} ), ...]
left_idx = [(3547237440, [0,43]), (9547237440, [3])]
# 0, 43, 3 are indices in the data list
# search 
min_left_idx = binary_search(left_idx, 3444444)
# now all rows referred to by left_idx[min_left_idx] ... left_idx[-1] will satisfy your criteria
min_right_idx = ...
# between these 2 all referred rows satisfy the range check
# intersect the sets
```

Comment: I tried doing something like that last week. The issue is that the dictionary is quite huge and it already takes lot of memory. Creating a new data structure like this and sorting them is quite slow and takes more than an hour to create such list.

Comment: Maybe interning the strings would lessen the memory pressure as you seem to have a lot of repeating ones. What about not loading all the data in memory? Keep just the indexing data structures in memory and all the country names and stuff in a db?

Comment: Now I see Benjamin's suggestion. Go try that.